# get all elements inside selected Element as an array of Element Jsoup android

Tags: java, android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

How to get the all Elements `<li>` inside `<ul>` in jsoup

I've select the `<ul>` using this code

```
 Elements elements = document.select("ul.small-list.width300");
```

so how to got it as `ArrayList` of `Elements`

Image may describe more :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specification, [`select()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) returns [`Elements`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) which is a *list of `Element`s*.

Add `> li` to your selector to get all `li` tags directly inside the `ul` element:

```
Elements elements = document.select("ul.small-list.width300 > li");
```

Comment: Thank you but if `<li>` tag contains other tags inside it how to get all tags inside each `<li>` tag ????

Comment: Thanks bro I found it `for (Element element : elements) {
     Log.d("-------------", element.child(0).nodeName());
     Log.d("-------------", element.child(1).nodeName());
     Log.d("-------------", element.child(2).nodeName());
     Log.d("-------------", "----------------------------");
    }`